# How to add color to horizontal bar graphs created by giving csv as an input using google charts?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, charts, google-visualization

I am a newbie to front end development. I am trying a demo example given on Google charts website. I am reading data from a csv file and able to generate a horizontal bar graph. Now i want to give colors to those bars but don't want to write those column names every time.

Below is the code i am referring to. How to read column names run time and color those bars?

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
  $.get("name.csv", function(csvString) {     
  var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0,1]);
 var options = {
    title: "Your data in bar format" ,
    hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
    vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
   legend: 'none'
 };
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
 chart.draw(view, options);
  } );

 }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Added in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at the code, the bars are actually represented by rows, not columns.
there are only two columns in the `DataView` --> `view.setColumns([0, 1]);`
first column is the name, second the value...

when using rows for the bars, the only way to provide a specific color,
is to use a `'style'` column,
you can add using a calculated column in the `DataView`.
the style column should follow the series column

i'm not sure *how* you want to assign each color,
but here is an example of adding the calculated `'style'` column.
you can *read the name* using --> `dt.getValue(row, 0)`

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, {
  role: 'style',
  type: 'string',
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    var color;
    switch (dt.getValue(row, 0)) {
      case 'A':
        color = 'red';
        break;

      case 'B':
        color = 'blue';
        break;

      default:
        color = 'green';
    }
    return color;
  }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks WhiteHat! It helped.